# Converting django modelForm to array

Tags: javascript, django

I have a javascript which depends on the django context variables.
Until now I solved that with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">{% include 'st_forms/main.js' %}</script>
```

And this include generates javascript from template and put in html page.

Now I want to make a global variable and make `main.js` as static. like this:

```
<script>
var global={{from_django_context}}
</script>
```

And then I can use global as variable in `main.js`.

But I have a little problem .
If mu context variable is ModelForm from django like this (`{{from_django_context}}`)

```
<tr><th><label for="id_sifraDrzave">Sifra drzave:</label></th><td><input id="id_sifraDrzave" maxlength="3" name="sifraDrzave" type="text" value="mil" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_naziv">Naziv:</label></th><td><input maxlength="4" name="naziv" type="text" /></td></tr>
```

How can I itterate through fields because variable is now string not array.
Before I used:

```
{% for field in from_django_context %}
{{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

And it's worked, but how to do this now, With global variable.
I hope you understand me.

Comment: You cannot iterate `global` because that is Javascript variable, not django context.

Comment: I know that i can't :). My question is how to solve this?

Comment: Maybe django have some tag for converting his variable to array or something...

Comment: I do not know your structure, but using ajax calls and set returning values sounds a better solution to your situation. But passing a ModelForm with javascript is quite a strange way...

Comment: Yes, I do agree with FallenAngel. "Converting" django context to Javascript variable is not always running seamlessly.

Comment: Uh... JSON? (create a view sending the data in a JSON array and fetch it using ajax, then do whatever)

Comment: Yes JSON is good solution. I need to repack modelform to some array and then send as json... Thanks.

Comment: Sidenote: that's really weird. Maybe you uh... want to tell us a little about what you're trying to solve, perhaps there's a little neater solution

Comment: I have table written in jquery and that table changes every time when someone click on link. Link's are refs to models... Also i use modelform for adding data to table... Because of that table is template...